# Make button size the same CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make the button size the same through out the CSS, but when the text is missing a few letters the size is thrown off

CSS:

```
  .btc {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.75em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 500px;
    color: #FFAA48;
    border: 2px solid #FFAA48;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(https://bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left 11px;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
  }
  .btc:hover {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFAA48;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FFAA48;
  }
```

Comment: Firstly, I'm not sure what the problem is. You are trying to make all buttons with this class the same size? Then why are there no width and height properties? And secondly, can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 .btc {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 0.75em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 500px;
    color: #FFAA48;
    border: 2px solid #FFAA48;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(https://bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left 11px;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btc:hover {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFAA48;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FFAA48;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize there was such an easy fix.

Comment: Glad I helped you.If you have any problem write.

Comment: For anyone trying to diff this out, the solution is `width: 100%;`